# Android studio does not allow me to write code

Tags: android

When I try to enter the code, such a cursor appears and I cannot enter it.
What is the problem?

[image]

Comment: Are you in overwrite mode? Try pressing insert on your keyboard

Comment: you cannot type anything? it looks like it is in insert mode....there will be a key called Ins or insert in you system try pressing that

Comment: If clicking Insert  didn't work then try clicking Escape , similar thing happens to me when I click ctrl+p for parameter info on Ubuntu

Comment: insert is not answer i user m1 makbook this is causer?

Comment: Did you try to restart the IDE?